# Passing a function to another function in a tax program

Tags: javascript

This is a class project and I am first year student. I am making a tax program and one function calculates the tax bracket the value falls into and the next function will format the value, concatenating dollar signs, adding decimals with the `.toFixed(2)` and will add appropriate commas with the `.toLocaleString()`. I am just trying to get the value to pass through the `formatMoney()` function so I can continue on with the rest of my coding. The exercise is fairly simple but being new it is difficult. Any help would be appreciated, again I just want the value to pass through the second function so I can progress with the rest of the coding which I can do, j

```
function calculateTax(money) {

    let initAmount = parseFloat(prompt("How much do you have?"));
    // The different taxes to be charged.
    let tax1 = .20;
    let tax2 = .15;
    let tax3 = .05;

    // Taking the user input and comparing it to which value if has to be calculated with.
    if (initAmount <= 5) {
        money = ((initAmount * tax1) + initAmount);

    } else if (initAmount <= 100) {
        money = ((initAmount * tax2) + initAmount);

    } else if (initAmount >= 100.01) {
        money = ((initAmount * tax3) + initAmount);

    } else if (Number.isNaN(initAmount)) {
        money = ("Invalid");

    }

    return (money);
}

calculateTax();
//This function will take the value of money from the calculateTax function and format as requested from client.

function formatMoney(money) {

    let x = money;

    console.log (x);
}

calculateTax(formatMoney(money));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have the nested functions reversed.  This code:

```
calculateTax(formatMoney(money));
```

says to pass the value of `money` to the `formatMoney` function and pass its results to the `calculateTax` function.

You presumably mean the reverse.  You want to pass the result of the `calculateTax` function to the `formatMoney` one:

```
formatMoney(calculateTax());
```

And presumably that will return a string -- even if you're only using `console.log` for now, so you will want to store the result in a variable:

```
let displayAmount = formatMoney(calculateTax());
```

---

That should solve your immediate problem, but if you're interested, there's two more issues you might want to address:

- You put the `isNaN` check at the end.  Generally best practice is to put such guards up front.
- Your `calculateTax` function declares the parameter `money`, but you never use it, simply redefining in your `if-else` blocks.  This is also not a great practice.  You would be better with local variable.  (`let number;`).  Or better, you might put the `prompt` outside the function and pass in that value to `calculateTax`.  This makes the `calculateTax` function more testable, and means your code is more modular.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code that you are looking for is below. Let me explain. This `console.log(calculateTax(100));` line starts the process by calling `calculateTax` and passing in `100` as the `initAmount` argument. Then the code runs through your `calculateTax` function. When it's done calculating the amount, it passes that amount to `formatMoney`, which makes it pretty (I just made up some code, if you want good formatting, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)).

```
//Example
console.log(calculateTax(100));

function calculateTax(initAmount) {

  let tax1 = .20;
  let tax2 = .15;
  let tax3 = .05;

  if (initAmount <= 5) { 
    money = ((initAmount * tax1) + initAmount);
  } else if (initAmount <= 100) {
    money = ((initAmount * tax2) + initAmount)
  } else if (initAmount >= 100.01) {
    money = ((initAmount * tax3) + initAmount);
  } else if (Number.isNaN(initAmount)) {
    money = ("Invalid");
  }

  let formattedMoney = formatMoney(money);
  return (formattedMoney);
}


function formatMoney(money) {
  let formattedMoney = '$' + money;
  return formattedMoney; 
}
```